# How do I set both height and width of image so that it can fit the size of my canvas in fabric.js?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

So I have an image in my canvas, and I am trying to make the image fit the canvas (I want image inside the canvas to be of the same size as the canvas). I use `scaleToWidth()` and `scaleToHeight()` to set the image size. But only one of them works. If I only use `scaleToWidth()` then it scales the width correctly, and if I only use `scaleToHeight()` then it scales the height correctly. In the code below, the height is being scaled correctly as it is written in the line below `oImg.scaleToWidth(cDim.clientWidth)`. But I want both the width and height to be according to my values. How can I do that?

```
                const canvas = new window.fabric.Canvas('c');
                const cDim = document.getElementById("canvas-dimension");
                console.log("Canvas Height: " + cDim.clientHeight);
                console.log("Canvas Width: " + cDim.clientWidth)
                let planURL = baseURL + "dream" + "/" +  "plan";
          

                window.fabric.Image.fromURL(planURL, (oImg) => {
                    
                    //let scaleW = cDim.clientWidth / oImg.getWidth;
                    // let scaleH = cDim.clientHeight / oImg.getHeight;
                   // oImg.scaleX(scaleW)

                    oImg.scaleToWidth(cDim.clientWidth)
                    oImg.scaleToHeight(cDim.clientHeight)
             
      
                    canvas.setBackgroundImage(oImg);
                    canvas.renderAll();

                },{ crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});
                setCanvas(canvas)
```

Any help or workaround to this will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

So I used this approach instead of `scaleToWidth` and `scaleToHeight`, and it worked!

```
let scaleW = cDim.clientWidth / oImg.width;
let scaleH = cDim.clientHeight / oImg.height;
oImg.set({
     opacity: 1,
     scaleX: scaleW,
     scaleY: scaleH,
});
```